# Apply same symbology to many raster layers in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, layers, symbology

I have many TIFF files (100+) that need to have the same symbology using the unique value option. Is there a quick way in arc 10.3 to do this?

Comment: I tried using this tool, http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13128 , however I don't think it works for ver 10. I'm not really sure how else to tackle so many rasters

Comment: As someone new to the site be sure to take the [Tour].  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that can be used to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: What options do you have available? Can you code in VB.net/VBA, C# or python? If you can't do scripting then, no, there isn't an easy way; conversely if you can script/program please indicate what language(s) you have at least casual ability in.

Comment: I have never had to write a script in Arc before, and only have basic knowledge in VB.

Answer (score 5):

Using python in the ArcMap python window you can use the following code. This will apply symbology from a specified layer file for all layers in a group layer. So 1) create a layer file with the symbology you want - think of the layer file as a template that you will apply to all layers. 2) place all your 100 TIFFs into a group layer called 'Group' 3) Provide the filepath of the layer file in the python code where I have marked 'XXXXXXX'.

```py
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
groupName = "Group"
lyrFile = "XXXXXXX"
allLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, groupName, df)[0]
for layer in allLayers:
     arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrFile)
     layer.visible = "True"
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a python toolbox for that, link to it:

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b282ba43695c401aa75d32336eaca82f

Description from the website:

> The toolbox simply allows one to copy the symbology from one layer
>   opened in ArcMap and paste (apply) it to one or more other layers
>   loaded in the table of contents (TOC). Works on rasters (images) and
>   feature layers. For example, it is good for defining a single image
>   with the outside collar (usually 0) to transparent and then applying
>   this setting to many images.