# Arcgis apply lyr file to multiple layers in workspace

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I've adapted some code from [Apply same symbology to many raster layers in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184940) and the [ESRI noticeboards](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/65545#comment-301008) to batch apply a .lyr file to several hundred .TIF files:

```
import arcpy
#Specifies mxd
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"PATHTOMXD\ModelVisuals.mxd")

#Specifies layer file with the symbology you want to apply to the other raster layers
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"PATHTOLAYERFILE\FloodDepths.lyr")

#Loops through layers in the mxd
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,""):
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, sourceLayer)
```

The code runs fine with no errors and it loops through the rasters, locking them one by one, but it doesn't apply the symbology layer or turn them on.

I am very rusty with python for ArcGIS.  What am I doing wrong or is there a better way of doing it?

####

**Update:**

This code ([from this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184940/apply-same-symbology-to-many-raster-layers-in-arcmap)) works perfectly:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame
groupName = "Group"
lyrFile = "XXXXXXX"
allLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, groupName, df)[0]
for layer in allLayers:
     arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer, lyrFile)
     layer.visible = "True"
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

What is the purpose of the "[0]" at the end of the allLayers line?  Although it is in the [code snippets here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm) it isn't explained.

Comment: is this running in arcgis or standalone? if standalone you should define your workspace arcpy.env,workspace =

Comment: Desktop 10.3 so standalone.  Adding "arcpy.env.workspace = "XXX:\My_Documents\GIS DataBase"" doesn't make any odds.

Comment: Are you running this code snippet from a Python script tool, the Python window of ArcMap, IDLE (or another IDE), ...?

Answer (score 2):

turning the layer visibility on is not something this tool does. It should only change the rendering properties. You will need to add mxd.save() to have the changes persist

```
...
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,""):
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr, sourceLayer)
    lyr.visible = True
mxd.save()
```